# Как открыть исходник сайта на Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

Ситуация смешная, устроился на работу frontend-разработчиком, не имея опыта в вэб-разработке, обещали научить (сам на C++ писал). Проблема такая: есть работающий сайт, развернутый на стороннем сервере. Мне дали задачу отредактировать скрипт формы отчета. Предоставили архив исходника сайта, в нём файлы и папки Wordpress и phpmyadmin. Вопрос: как открыть "копию" сайта? Как его развернуть на локальном сервере?
Установил Apache, PHP, MySql, бросил туда исходники, но на Wordpress открывается дефолтная страница[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UP1 : Перекинул всё через Duplicator, развернул на Wamp Server, в результате посыпались ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И не надо тут нам фронтендерских коллажей. Это бессмысленые картинки. Смузи ещё добавьте. Потрудитесь оформить сообщения об ошибках текстом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress - это файлы php и база mysql. Без правильно импортированной базы вы копию сайта не увидите.

Используйте плагин Duplicator, он корректно перенесёт сайт на новое место, в том числе на локальный сервер.

Comment: Всё перекинул через Duplicator, развернул на WAMP Server, в результате высыпало ошибки

Comment: Ну это не Duplicator проблемы, а ваши. Сравните версии php для начала.

Answer (score 0):

1. Скопируйте все файлы сервера по FTP.
2. Сделайте дамп базы через phpmyadmin или аналогичные программы (adminer и т.п.)
3. Откройте в скачанных файлах из п.1 файл wp-config.php и поменяйте там данные доступа к базе данных на новую.
4. Откройте дамп базы из п.2 через текстовый редактор и сделайте массовую замену Старый_домен -> Новый_домен
5. Залейте все файлы из п.3 на новый сайт.
6. Выполните на новом сервере в phpmyadmin SQL- запрос с измененным дампом базы данных из п.4. Ну или разверните этот дамп другими программами.

ПС: Убедитесь что на шагу номер 4 вы не накосячили с http:// https:// и www

Comment: Да сколько же можно. Когда уже закончатся эти вредные советы - как сломать базу. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/

Comment: KAGG, спасибо. А разве вот эти записи с относительными путями и количеством строк в базе не перезаписываются после первого же запуска плагина? У меня за всю историю пользования этой схемы проблемы были один раз - ломались настройки темы и я не мог понять почему. Теперь понял. В остальных случаях все переносится нормально.

Comment: После запуска какого плагина? В любом случае - ничего глобально в базе не перезаписывается. Ваша схема работает только на простых сайтах, где нет сериализованных данных. Если они есть - ваш способ ломает базу.